# vmware ESXi 5.0 snapshot backup failed “500 internal server error”

Tags: backup, esxi

I'm trying to backup virtual machine on ESXi 5.0 using Trilead Vm Explorer 3.7 but I'm getting 500 internal server error:

1) Snapshot is created.

2) Files download started. Some files have been downloaded, but when -flat.vmdk file download starts, after 3-4 minutes download interrupted with "500 internal server error".

I tried to download manually using SSH(WinSCP) but same thing, -flat.vmdk file download starts and after 3-4 minutes download interrupted with SCP error.

I have three virtual machines on one datastore. lockdown mode is disabled.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error can be that, the vmdk file is in use and being updated during the download. You can try to shut the virtual machine down first and try downloading the vmdk file again.